# Deploying ASP.Net MVC web application on the AT&T server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have developed an ASP.Net MVC web application and transferred all the files on the server but when I go to that address it shows an error: "Not Authorized to View This Page [CFN #0004]". I had contacted the support team, they said there is nothing wrong from their side and asked to check the application code. They saved a webpage with extension ".aspx" for testing which runs without any problem.
I have tested my code on local IIS server on my system, it is tested and works perfectly fine.

I do not know how to get the application running on the server now. I feel stuck.
This is the first time I am deploying web application on the server. Do not have any prior experience. Expecting some guidance especially with **AT&T web server**. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of an AT&T server. Is this server rack space which you rent? Or is it free with your home AT&T model subscription? 

How is your site deployed, ftp? What are the file permissions set to?

did you google the error? I found this page which might help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-authorized-to-view-this-page/

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. AT&T is a web hosting service provider. Deployed using Web Deploy option in Visual Studio